# Why has db:create stopped working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration

Until recently `db:create` worked just fine, but now it is failing with the stacktrace I've posted below. It's a `String can't be coerced into Fixnum` error.

What could be the cause of this?

My password contains letters as well as numbers, so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765834/cant-convert-fixnum-to-string-during-rake-dbcreate) can't be the cause.

The trace only points to Rails code, not my own code, which makes debugging a challenge.

I commented out the methods in my models that use the `+` operator, but that didn't solve anything.

My `database.yml`:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: db/testivate_development
  pool: 5
  username: steven
  password: <redacted>
  host: localhost

test: &test
  adapter: postgresql
  database: db/testivate_test<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>
  pool: 5
  username: steven
  password: <redacted>
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: db/testivate_production
  pool: 5
  username: steven
  password:

cucumber:
  <<: *test
```

The trace:

```
$ rake db:create
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.7.8, but has dynamically loaded 2.9.0
String can't be coerced into Fixnum
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/enumstats-0.0.3/lib/enumstats/enumerable.rb:3:in `+'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/enumstats-0.0.3/lib/enumstats/enumerable.rb:3:in `block in sum'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/enumstats-0.0.3/lib/enumstats/enumerable.rb:3:in `each'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/enumstats-0.0.3/lib/enumstats/enumerable.rb:3:in `inject'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/enumstats-0.0.3/lib/enumstats/enumerable.rb:3:in `sum'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:749:in `create_database'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:130:in `rescue in create_database'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:74:in `create_database'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:62:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:62:in `each'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:62:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/steven/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "database"=>"db/testivate_development", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"steven", "password"=>"<redacted>", "host"=>"localhost"}
String can't be coerced into Fixnum
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/enumstats-0.0.3/lib/enumstats/enumerable.rb:3:in `+'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/enumstats-0.0.3/lib/enumstats/enumerable.rb:3:in `block in sum'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/enumstats-0.0.3/lib/enumstats/enumerable.rb:3:in `each'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/enumstats-0.0.3/lib/enumstats/enumerable.rb:3:in `inject'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/enumstats-0.0.3/lib/enumstats/enumerable.rb:3:in `sum'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:749:in `create_database'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:130:in `rescue in create_database'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:74:in `create_database'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:62:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:62:in `each'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:62:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/steven/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "database"=>"db/testivate_test", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"steven", "password"=>"<redacted>", "host"=>"localhost"}
```

**UPDATE**

I get the same error even when I move all migrations from `/db/migrations/` go for the simplest and most explicit `database.yml` possible:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: db/testivate_development
  username: "steven"
  password: "<redacted>"
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: db/testivate_test
  username: "steven"
  password: "<redacted>"
  host: localhost
```

Comment: Have you upgraded the OS that you are running this code on ?  It could be a side effect from the warning flagged about Nokogiri or potentially another gem which needs recompilation.

Comment: Thanks Grant. I haven't recently upgraded the OS but I'll recompile Nokogiri etc just to be sure.

Comment: Steven - try forcing the password to be string by surrounding with "" so that the YAML parser doesn't try to coerce to a Fixnum.  Just realised you had linked to this in another SO question/answer.  Have you tried this anyhow ?

Comment: With all my usernames and passwords in quote marks I still get the `String can't be coreced into Fixnum` error.

Comment: Looks like the bug is in the `enumstats` gem. Are you including it in your Gemfile?

Comment: You are correct. Thanks. I'll report the issue to Enumstats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the bug is in the enumstats gem. Are you including it in your Gemfile?